# Automate VLAN Configuration through TCL

Tags: cisco

I am looking to implement Automation to VLAN config:

ios_config - does not suit my automation because I need to have the user input VLAN name and VLAN number as well int VLAN and IP address subnet mask of SVI. Any other TCL function I can use to complete this script? Like this:

Enter VLAN ID: 
Enter VLAN name: 
Enter VLAN IP address: 
Enter VLAN Subnet mask:

ios_config: "no shut"

Regards,

Comment: I do not really get your point. Automation still needs your input (by hand or by input file) to generate output. Can you give us an example?

Comment: Hi, say I am configuring to generate VLAN 10 -  ios_config "vlan 10" "name test_10" "end". However, for implementation VLAN 10 is not constant VLAN it can be anything from 1-4094, I want to have a function that can perform input VLAN number and IP address, subnet mask for VLAN interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a function/procedure (with commands) to achieve this:

- To write to screen/a channel, use: **puts**
- To read input or a single line from screen/a channel, use: **gets**
- To retrieve a value from a variable, use: **$**
- To run a Cisco IOS configuration command, use: **ios_config**

The following simple procedure/script asks you to enter a VLAN ID and its name, then it will configure that VLAN on your device:

```
//Configure your TCL procedure:

#tclsh
(tcl)#proc Vlanconfig {} { 
+>puts "Enter VLAN ID: " ; 
+>gets stdin VLANid 
+>puts "Enter VLAN Name:" ; 
+>gets stdin VLANname
+>ios_config "vlan $VLANid" "name $VLANname" "end"
+>}
(tcl)#


//Run your procedure:

(tcl)#Vlanconfig
Enter VLAN ID: 
200
Enter VLAN Name:
Users

(tcl)#tclquit
#show vlan
VLAN Name                             Status
...
200  Users                            active
...
```

You can expand this procedure to configure L3 Int VLAN and its IP address as you what.

I hope it is helpful and you have an idea of how to build your own TCL procedure.

Comment: Yeah this is noice! I scale from here thanks! Let me try this